# How to parse unnest json data using cypher query language to neo4j database?

Tags: json, python-2.7, neo4j, cypher

In the below json file I want to access **"934934507945312256", "934934503604174848",....** and then the keys inside them.
But after using **UNWIND clause** I am unable to access the data of these keys(quote_count,reply_count,etc.) as these keys("934934507945312256" ,"934934503604174848",...) are randomly generated.

```
    {
    "934934507945312256": {
    "quote_count": 0,
    "reply_count": 0,
    "hashtags": null,
    "datetime": "2017-11-26 23:58:51",
    "date": "2017-11-26",
    "like_count": 0,
    "verified": "False",
    "sentiment": 0,
    "author": "JudyThe Resistance",
    "location": "Hollywood, California USA",
    "tid": "934934507945312256",
    "retweet_count": 0,
    "type": "retweet",
    "media_list": null,
    "quoted_source_id": null,
    "url_list": null,
    "tweet_text": "RT @kylegriffin1: Reminder: The Senate Judiciary Committee gave Jared Kushner a November 27 deadline to turn over the missing records… ",
    "author_profile_image": "https://pbs.twimg.com/profi...",
    "author_screen_name": "jgirl66",
    "author_id": "23737528",
    "lang": "en",
    "keywords_processed_list": [
    "reminder",
    "senate judiciary committee",
    "kushner november",
    "deadline"
    ],
    "retweet_source_id": "934872065471115264",
    "mentions": [
    "kylegriffin1"
    ],
    "replyto_source_id": null
    },
    "934934503604174848": {
    "quote_count": 0,
    "reply_count": 2,
    "hashtags": [
    "MissUniverse",
    "Thailand"
    ],
    "datetime": "2017-11-26 23:58:50",
    "date": "2017-11-26",
    "like_count": 38,
    "verified": "False",
    "sentiment": 0,
    "author": "P'Hmee7.5",
    "location": "Bangkok, Thailand",
    "tid": "934934503604174848",
    "retweet_count": 105,
    "type": "Tweet",
    "media_list": null,
    "quoted_source_id": null,
    "url_list": null,
    "tweet_text": "รอโหวต มรญ #MissUniverse #Thailand",
    "author_profile_image": "
    Thumbnail
    ",
    "author_screen_name": "Peehmee75",
    "author_id": "700720806972624897",
    "lang": "th",
    "keywords_processed_list": null,
    "retweet_source_id": null,
    "mentions": null,
    "replyto_source_id": null
    },
    "934934336381636608": {
    "quote_count": 0,
    "reply_count": 0,
    "hashtags": null,
    "datetime": "2017-11-26 23:58:10",
    "date": "2017-11-26",
    "like_count": 0,
    "verified": "False",
    "sentiment": 0,
    "author": "selfresqingprncess",
    "location": "Maine, USA",
    "tid": "934934336381636608",
    "retweet_count": 0,
    "type": "retweet",
    "media_list": null,
    "quoted_source_id": null,
    "url_list": null,
    "tweet_text": "RT @kylegriffin1: Reminder: The Senate Judiciary Committee gave Jared Kushner a November 27 deadline to turn over the missing records… ",
    "author_profile_image": "https://pbs.twimg.com/profi...",
    "author_screen_name": "slfresqngprncss",
    "author_id": "100536014",
    "lang": "en",
    "keywords_processed_list": [
    "reminder",
"keywords_processed_list": [
            "reminder",
            "senate judiciary committee",
            "kushner november",
            "deadline"
        ],
        "retweet_source_id": "934872065471115264",
        "mentions": [
            "kylegriffin1"
        ],
        "replyto_source_id": null
    }
  }
```

There's I have tried :- 
**query =
 """
 
with {json} as data 
UNWIND data as doc 
FOREACH( l in doc| 
MERGE (label1:Label1 {author:l.author}))

"""**

But I am getting error:- 
**Cannot merge node using null property value for author.**

Comment: Can you please what you have tried so far and what's the problem you are facing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Your JSON file is malformed.

   A JSON string cannot contain control characters (like carriage returns or linefeeds). And your JSON contains an extraneous section (that is probably a copy/paste error):

   ```
   "keywords_processed_list": [
   "reminder",
   ```
2. Furthermore, [UNWIND](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/clauses/unwind/) can only be used with lists. You cannot use it to get the properties from a map. Once you have fixed your JSON errors, try the following query (I assume that `json` is a [parameter](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/syntax/parameters/) whose value is your JSON data):

   ```
   UNWIND KEYS($json) AS k
   MERGE(label1:Label1 {author: $json[k].author})
   ```

Comment: Thanks for your response , it worked. But can u tell me some resources where i can learn about all this. and can u explain me for what we are using  $json  ?

Comment: You can learn about parameters [here](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/syntax/parameters/), and UNWIND [here](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/clauses/unwind/).

Comment: Thanks for your response. But after creating a graph I am unable to retreive queries using MATCH clause.I wrote a script (MERGE(label1:author{name:$json[k].author,date_time:$json[k].datetime}) MERGE(label6:author{name:$json[k].lang,auth:$json[k].location})          MERGE (label1)-[:location_val]->(label6) )      and created the graph and now I am using MATCH ($json[k]) WHERE $json[k].name='en' RETURN $json[k].auth to access the data but getting no results.

Comment: Your second query makes no sense. You probably want `MATCH (x:author) WHERE x.name='en' RETURN x.auth`. Also: why does a location node have the `author` label?

Comment: I tried this above query too in my python script but got no results. I used this location node for author label just for making relation between nodes. The thing I need to do is to get all the tweet data of a author of last 7 days who so ever I want. So I thought of creating graph which contains data(tweets) of all authors so as to retrieve the data.

Comment: The above query(MATCH (x:author) WHERE x.name='en' RETURN x.auth) is working if I directly query on neo4j localserver but it's not working in my python script and I am not getting that how to retreive all tweet information of author of last 7 days if author name is given.

Comment: You should open a new question.